# Mailer Ruby Rails Heroku wrong sent mail to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, heroku, sendgrid, mailer

I'm having an issue where the Mailer function of rails is working fine locally. The Sent mail to function is sending to the correct email address specified in the email form submission. This feature is working fine.

The issue is when it's pushed to Heroku, the Send Mail to is my email address, regardless if I enter in other email addresses. Heroku logs do not show any errors. I check the database on Heroku, it has the correct email addresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by passing in the correct instance of the static variable. Now it's using the same email when the send confirmation method gets called.